# Local web apps and W3C standards

Tags: php, w3c, web-standards

If am writing a local app that will only run using a specific browser, am i setting my self up by slightly ignoring W3C's standards?  I ask this question because in this app i am thinking of using custom HTML tags, custom attributes, etc...

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: @waiwai933: XML has a standard: http://www.w3.org/XML/ ;)

Comment: @Alerty What I mean is that the OP mentions 'custom HTML tags' and 'custom attributes'. Isn't that what XML is for?

Comment: @waiwai933: There is a type of XML for the web and it is XHTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you should follow the standards. The reason is that technology evolves, but standards usually stays for a while.

Consider that a new version of the browser might not support what you are trying to do in the future. Do not believe people will stay with a certain version of a browser just to use a website. People might be obligated to change version for security reasons. Have you heard about the Aurora IE Exploit.

Here are some links about the exploit:

- http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/01/google-hack-attack/
- http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2010/01/hack-of-adob/
- http://blog.metasploit.com/2010/01/reproducing-aurora-ie-exploit.html

Also, take into consideration that the standards are meant to make everyone's job easier and everyone will understand the same thing. I believe that web developers should make content viewable and useable for as many people as possible and for as many browsers as possible. Have a look at the [W3C mission](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/mission).

Comment: +1 The standards are created for a very good reason. They make the developers life easier. I've seen a few web apps from students that I've hired that make use of their own custom tags. They were all quickly replaced by more maintainable code.

Answer (score 3):

This is *practically* probably OK - you could pull it off, if you can guarantee the following:

- The users will always use the same approved browser
- The requirements will not change
- The app design can be maintained in the future

I would go the W3C standards compliant way though.

Answer (score 0):

As others are saying, stick with the standards.  I would also add, however, that applications always get used more widely than expected, and hang around longer than expected - so it will almost certainly end up being used on other browsers.

Besides, writing in a (more or less) standards compliant way is easier than writing non-compliant code anyway!

Comment: It might be faster to write non-standard code, but in the end it will take more time to maintain the code. One example I can give you for this is the separation of style from structure.

Comment: If you do not separate the style, the code will become cluttered and you will have to change the style at multiple places instead of a single place such as in another file.